# Directed Sparsest Cut on Planar Graphs?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The (uniform) directed sparsest cut problem asks for a cut $(S,\bar{S})$ in a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ which minimize the ratio $\frac{\delta_{out}(S) }{|S||\bar{S}|}$, where $\delta_{out}$ is the total capacity of edges coming out from $S$. The best approximation ratio for the problem is $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ via the paper *$O(\sqrt{\log n})$ approximation algorithms for min UnCut, min 2CNF deletion, and directed cut problems*.

The undirected version of the problem on planar graphs have a factor two approximation algorithm:  [Finding separator cuts in planar graphs within twice the optimal](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=365709&tag=1) !
Does anybody aware of a similar result for directed sparsest cut on planar graphs ? Can we apply the same technique for the undirected version to get a constant ratio?

Comment: The problem is open even now as far as I know.

Comment: It seems to me that this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.15187 provides an answer.